# How make a animated dashed line (path) in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Consider a line that grow like this fiddle.

```css
 svg #path {
    stroke-dasharray: 19;
    stroke-dashoffset: 19;
    animation: dash 4s linear 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 19;
    }

    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
                <svg viewBox="0 1 4.8666667 7.2777778" width="438px" height="655px">
                    <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="darkgoldenrod" stroke-width=".06" stroke-dashoffset="19" stroke-dasharray="19"
                          d="M 3.5465404,3.034946 C 3.4354313,3.6265215 4.030817,3.0359535 4.1671536,3.55319 4.2794157,4.1144845 3.4363811,4.1431996 3.0741807,4.4032244 2.4391877,4.9662761 4.4061645,6.2801514 4.3786782,6.7247724 4.4096446,7.0948023 4.0390679,7.0007891 3.8245189,7.429004 3.7009337,7.6691977 3.3346032,7.6270496 2.8948462,7.6490553 2.4536728,7.6318087 1.6152485,7.8291298 1.0767182,7.6694802 0.73107147,7.5240403 0.80398481,7.2706043 0.80398481,7.2706043 0.83861231,6.866754 1.5732839,7.0445965 1.7753715,6.5292039 1.953487,5.950891 1.7063462,5.2323625 1.511576,5.18339 1.1230225,5.0822327 0.82998045,5.712977 0.41672909,5.2491666 0.28482631,5.098227 0.24895285,4.7880749 0.46248017,4.5821824 0.7446934,4.3573654 1.0821233,4.6451318 1.3127029,4.5397796 c 0.1144564,-0.024614 0.030353,-0.2123847 0.0053,-0.9407053">
                    </path>
                </svg>
```

But how i do this with a dashed line? i use "stroke-dashoffset" to make path animate so i cant use it to make path dashed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a longer `stroke-dasharray` for it. I guess you have to play a bit with the values to get it right.

```css
 svg #path {
    stroke-dasharray: 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 19;
    stroke-dashoffset: 19;
    animation: dash 4s linear 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 19;
    }

    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
                <svg viewBox="0 1 4.8666667 7.2777778" width="438px" height="655px">
                    <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="darkgoldenrod" stroke-width=".06" stroke-dashoffset="19" stroke-dasharray="19"
                          d="M 3.5465404,3.034946 C 3.4354313,3.6265215 4.030817,3.0359535 4.1671536,3.55319 4.2794157,4.1144845 3.4363811,4.1431996 3.0741807,4.4032244 2.4391877,4.9662761 4.4061645,6.2801514 4.3786782,6.7247724 4.4096446,7.0948023 4.0390679,7.0007891 3.8245189,7.429004 3.7009337,7.6691977 3.3346032,7.6270496 2.8948462,7.6490553 2.4536728,7.6318087 1.6152485,7.8291298 1.0767182,7.6694802 0.73107147,7.5240403 0.80398481,7.2706043 0.80398481,7.2706043 0.83861231,6.866754 1.5732839,7.0445965 1.7753715,6.5292039 1.953487,5.950891 1.7063462,5.2323625 1.511576,5.18339 1.1230225,5.0822327 0.82998045,5.712977 0.41672909,5.2491666 0.28482631,5.098227 0.24895285,4.7880749 0.46248017,4.5821824 0.7446934,4.3573654 1.0821233,4.6451318 1.3127029,4.5397796 c 0.1144564,-0.024614 0.030353,-0.2123847 0.0053,-0.9407053">
                    </path>
                </svg>
```